# Uso de ándale y ándele

Tags: uso-de-palabras, méxico

¿Hay diferencia entre esas expresiones?
Según el diccionario, ambas quieren decir *"hurry up!"* y son principalmente mexicanas, pero ¿puede la primera significar otras cosas? ¿O no? Estoy un poco confundido.

¿Por qué se pone el objeto indirecto 'le' especialmente en en la cosa menos formal, ándale?

Comment: Me gusta decir "que le estés andando".

Comment: @MichaelWolf - Nunca he oído eso.  ¿Dónde has oído esa frase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ándale` se le puede decir a una persona con la que tienes confianza, mientras que `Ándele`, hacia una persona con la que aún no tienes mucha confianza.

Digamos que la segunda va en un tono más formal, pero utilizar la expresión mexicana **ándale**, en ninguno de los casos me parece algo formal.

Otro ejemplo de estos casos podría ser: escríbeme/escríbame

Comment: +1. I agree. The only difference is that one of these forms (ánd**e**le) is used the _usted_ for instead of the _de tú_ form.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero tengo otra pregunta, por qué pone el objeto indirecto 'le' especialmente en en la cosa menos formal, ándale?

Comment: @Borges así es la expresión mexicana "ándale", sólo se usa de este modo en México, es un español coloquial. Un correcto español sería simplemente decir "anda" o "ande" que significa "go". Pero "ándale" vendría a ser como "hurry up" o "come on".

Answer (score 2):

En Sinaloa (en el norte de México):

1. Ándale muchacho ( "Ponte en acción" muchacho,  parecido al "DALE" usado por los españoles.)
2. Ándale no seas así por favor.. (Usado más para pedir un favor)
3. ¡¡¡ Ándale !!! ( !! Dios Mio= Oh My god = Valgame Dios) como expresión de asombro.

Comment: Entiendo que con las dos primeras puedes decir tanto "ándale" como "ándele", pero para el tercer caso no tiene mucho sentido usar el ustedeo.

Answer (score 0):

*Material suplementario:*

También se usa en México para estas situaciones:

(a) A se está esforzando por entender algo.  Después de un diálogo con B, y cierto esfuerzo, A formula una hipótesis, por ejemplo, "O sea que la política anti-inmigración de Trump salió favoreciendo la izquierda en las elecciones mexicanas?"  B puede responder con

> Ándale, eso es.

(O si le hable de usted a B, entonces diría más bien "Ándele.")

Quiere decir "Sí, ya captaste la idea.  Muy bien."

(b) A le hace una propuesta a B, por ejemplo, "¿Por qué no aprovechamos las vacaciones escolares para hacer una visita a Lugar X?"  Si a B le parece una idea genial, le puede responder

> Ándale, sí, por qué no.  Vamos, pues.

¿Por qué se le pone el "le" al final?

Es una costumbre muy común en el lenguaje informal en México, para muchas expresiones, por ejemplo

Órale.
Quiúbole.
Válgame dios.

Tengo dos ideas sobre esto.

1. Es una imitación de expresiones que *requieren* el "le", porque suenan bien, como por ejemplo "Dígale".
2. Cuando uno quiere tratar de persuadir a alguien de algo, se usa lenguaje así: "Límpiame el patio, por favor," lo cual quiere decir *Hazme el favor de limpiar el patio.*  Ahí el "me" al final *personaliza* la expresión.  Creo que de la misma manera, agregar un "le" al final ejerce cierta presión, cierta insinuación, como "por favorcito".